# Middle align elements with image without wrapping in div?

Tags: html, css

Trying to help a friend with her Squarespace site. On the homepage is a list of articles, and under the titles are images floated to the left of a caption, a button, and a div with some span links. The caption, button, and span links are not wrapped in their own div, unfortunately.

**It's important to note that I cannot change the actual HTML structure here**, otherwise this would be super easy. **My only options are CSS and javascript.**

You can check out the HTML at the website here: http://aikaslovecloset.com

Notice how the caption aligns with the top of the image, which looks kinda bad on taller images. Yes, I've suggested that she only uses horizontal images, but I guess that's not ideal for a style blogger. Does anyone have any crazy CSS tricks to push that down to the middle of the image, responsive to image height?

Comment: Much easier and faster to help if you show (image or some other way) what exactly the problem is...

Comment: I think you screwed yourself by not wrapping the extra elements (caption/button) in their own container.

Comment: @TylerSebastian I didn't write the HTML code. It's part of the Squarespace template the way it came, and the only way I can change the source code is by enabling "Developer Mode" which disables all the drag and drop editing for her. If I had the option of wrapping things in divs, I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh, some people will hate this (and rightly so), but there is a way if it's an absolute necessity (however you decide to determine that) by using jQuery DOM manipulation. Simply put, append each `.entry-footer` to the previous sibling with the class `.entry-content`. Then in each `.entry-content`, wrap every child element (which now includes the footer) except the `.excerpt-thumb` in a new div. Style `.entry-thumb` and the new div as `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;`. Make sure to remove the float from `.entry-thumb`.

I've simplified the code for demonstrative purposes:

```js
$('.view-list .entry-footer').each( function(){
      $(this).appendTo($(this).prev('.entry-content'));          
});
$('.view-list .entry-content').each(function(){
  $(this).children().not('.excerpt-thumb').wrapAll('<div class="new-div" />');
});
```

```css
article {
 display: block; 
}
.excerpt-thumb {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 1.5em 1.5em 0;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 67%;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.entry-title, .entry-content {
    text-align: center;
}
.clear::after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.entry-footer {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
.excerpt-thumb img {
    height: auto !important;
    left: auto !important;
    top: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
.new-div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="view-list">
<article>
<header class="entry-header">article 1</header>
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="excerpt-thumb">
    <img data-image-focal-point="0.45806318271659807,0.5180000305175781" data-image-dimensions="2500x3750" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 544px; height: 816px; position: relative;" alt="Silk Feel, Slip Dress Obsession " class="" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg?format=750w" data-image-resolution="750w">
  </div>
  <div class="p-summary">
  article 1 p-summary
  </div>
  <p class="entry-more-link">article 1 entry-more-link</p>
</div>
<footer class="entry-footer clear">article 1 footer</footer>
</article>
<article>
<header class="entry-header">article 2</header>
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="excerpt-thumb">
    <img data-image-focal-point="0.45806318271659807,0.5180000305175781" data-image-dimensions="2500x3750" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 544px; height: 816px; position: relative;" alt="Silk Feel, Slip Dress Obsession " class="" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/579e8e0a37c581f9480799ab/579e8ee42109d3fc32bf7bcb/57eb59d2e6f2e1db2856bb18/1475374638274/Aika+Testing+testing+1+2+3-Aika-0049.jpg?format=750w" data-image-resolution="750w">
  </div>
  <div class="p-summary">
  article 2 p-summary
  </div>
  <p class="entry-more-link">article 2 entry-more-link</p>
</div>
<footer class="entry-footer clear">article 2 footer</footer>
</article>
</div>
```

It's gross, but it's there. But the solution you seek is not possible with the HTML the way it currently is.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this looks like a pretty complete solution. I'm going to give this and another answer (below) a try and update when it's tested. Thanks again!

Comment: Just implemented it, and it works beautifully. Now if only I can convince her to go 50% width on the two divs instead of 67%. One step at a time. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: Great to hear @JesseRogers. I agree that with those taller images, the text starts to feel a bit adrift. Ah well. We must pick our battles -- like breaking semantics for the sake of appearance. ;) All the best.

Answer (score 1):

When I deal with Squarespace and get into this kind of troubles, I use Jquery to wrap things(Dirty solution but it works)

`$(".p-summary, .entry-more-link").wrapAll( "<div></div>" );`

This piece of code wraps the caption and the button in a div.

Comment: Definitely gotten around a few things with jQuery already in Squarespace. I'll try this first, and if I can't make it work, I'll try Daniel's. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'padding-top' only on the 'p-summary' class:

```
.p-summary {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```